# rails generate devise:install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have added `gem 'devise'` to my gemfile and when I run `rails generate devise:install`, I get the following error:

```
Greg-Nowickis-MacBook-Pro:radiusapp Greg_Nowicki$ rails generate devise:install
Could not find orm_adapter-0.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I went ahead and did a `bundle install`, but I get the same error. FYI, I have also create an rvm gemset 'radiusapp' for this project and have checked that I am using it while trying to install devise.

Here's a snapshot of my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'orm_adapter', '~> 0.5.0'

# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

And the link to the rest of the project: https://github.com/nowgeez/radiusapp

Here's the `$bundle list` output:

```
Greg-Nowickis-MacBook-Pro:radiusapp Greg_Nowicki$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (4.1.0)
  * actionpack (4.1.0)
  * actionview (4.1.0)
  * activemodel (4.1.0)
  * activerecord (4.1.0)
  * activesupport (4.1.0)
  * arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
  * bcrypt (3.1.7)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.5.3)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.1)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
  * devise (3.2.4)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (2.0.2)
  * hike (1.2.3)
  * i18n (0.6.9)
  * jbuilder (2.0.6)
  * jquery-rails (3.1.0)
  * json (1.8.1)
  * mail (2.5.4)
  * mime-types (1.25.1)
  * minitest (5.3.3)
  * multi_json (1.9.2)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * polyglot (0.3.4)
  * rack (1.5.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.2)
  * rails (4.1.0)
  * railties (4.1.0)
  * rake (10.3.1)
  * rdoc (4.1.1)
  * sass (3.2.19)
  * sass-rails (4.0.3)
  * sdoc (0.4.0)
  * spring (1.1.2)
  * sprockets (2.11.0)
  * sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
  * sqlite3 (1.3.9)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.3)
  * tilt (1.4.1)
  * treetop (1.4.15)
  * turbolinks (2.2.2)
  * tzinfo (1.1.0)
  * uglifier (2.5.0)
  * warden (1.2.3)
```

Also, here's my $PATH

```
Greg-Nowickis-MacBook-Pro:radiusapp Greg_Nowicki$ $PATH
-bash: /Users/Greg_Nowicki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@radiusapp/bin:/Users/Greg_Nowicki/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/Greg_Nowicki/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/Greg_Nowicki/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin: No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, I ran it after adding the gem. I also ran it after the error.

Comment: I've checked out your project, bundled it and the devise:install run correctly. Try `bundle exec rails g devise:install`.

Comment: thanks for trying that, but I get the same error.

Comment: Could you run `bundle list` and show the results?

Comment: try running `bundle update` to force rebuild the gemfile then `rails generate devise:install`

Comment: @artmees just ran 'bundle update' and 'rails generate devise:install' - same error.

Comment: `bundle update` not `bundle install`

Comment: @artmees sorry, that's what I ran and what I meant to write..

Comment: have you tried uninstalling devise gem using `gem uninstall devise` then `gem install devise` to install it globally then run `bundle install --local` then `rails generate devise:install` ? might work

Comment: I'm deeply ashamed.. looks like I created a folder and app with the same name some where along the line. Therefore, I was trying to run commands on the folder.. thank you for your time and efforts, appreciate it! --- everything works as intended and valuable lesson learned.